# HTML/CSS: Div in Background matching containing text

Tags: html, css, overflow, border

I've a container div with id `container` around.

Inside, I've got a div with id `inside` which can contain a Text which is *wider* than the container div. The text should not be wrapped.

As summary, thats how it looks like actually:

```
_____DIV CONTAINER________________________
|'---DIV INSIDE--------------------------|----------------
|'                                       |               '
|' here it contains some long text which is very long    '
|'                                       |               '
|'---------------------------------------|---------------'
|________________________________________|
```

Now, I want it to look like this:

```
_____DIV CONTAINER________________________
|'---DIV INSIDE--------------------------|
|'                                       |
|' here it contains some long text which |
|'                                       |
|'---------------------------------------|
|________________________________________|
```

Like this it should look like and a horizontal scroll bar in the bottom should be displayed.

If I solve this, the inner div shows the right border inside the CONTAINER, but the text is continuing. So it accidentally looks like this:

```
_____DIV CONTAINER_____________________________
|'---DIV INSIDE------------------------'      |
|'                                     '      |
|' here it contains some long text whic'h look| [and here's the text under the container]
|'                                     '      |
|'--------------------------------------      |
|_____________________________________________|
```

As i just saw, it should look right like here in stack:

```
........................................................look at the border here |  very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text
```

The text goes under the inline div border but does not wrap. This is what I want to reach. How can I solve this?

Comment: What exactly do you want?  I got lost on your third picture...

Comment: I just want to have no text wrap, but the text hiding behind the container-div (the outer one)

Comment: did you try `#container {overflow: scroll}` in your css?

Comment: This worked if I use it on inside div! Thanks ;) could you write an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set the container div's overflow property to scroll:

```
#container {
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to set your parent div to `overflow: scroll`.

Comment: Oops, J Max can post this as an answer. I didn't see his comment before answering.

Answer (score 1):

have a 3rd div within the "inside" that doesn't have in your case a set width and allows for overflow.

this will mean that the content within inside will overflow however not alter the size of inside and it parent divs.

also two helpful css rules that maybe handy to apply to the div within inside:

```
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

(that will only show the x bar).

Hope this helps?